# on the order relation of the derivatives of two functions intersecting at a differentiable point

Tags: calculus

Consider two functions $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that hold the same value at a differentiable point $\bar{x}\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e., $g(\bar{x})=f(\bar{x})$ and both derivatives $f'(\bar{x})$ and $g'(\bar{x})$ exist.

Suppose that $f(x)$ is not smaller than $g(x)$ in a right neighborhood of $\bar{x}$, i.e., there exists a sufficiently small $\delta>0$ such that
$$f(x)\geq g(x),\quad \forall x\in (\bar{x},\bar{x}+\delta).$$

Can we conclude that $f'(\bar{x})\geq g'(\bar{x})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(x)\geq g(x)$ on $(\overline{x},\overline{x}+\delta)$, with equality at $\overline{x}$, we can conclude

$$\frac{f(\overline{x}+h) - f(\overline{x})}{h} \geq \frac{g(\overline{x}+h) - g(\overline{x})}{h} $$
for all $h\in (0,\delta)$.  Hence taking $h\to 0$ the inequality holds for the one-sided or "right" derivatives:
$$f'(\overline{x}) = \lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(\overline{x}+h) - f(\overline{x})}{h} \geq \lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{g(\overline{x}+h) - g(\overline{x})}{h} = g'(\overline{x})$$

To justify the equality on the left and right above, we are given that $f'(\overline{x})$ and $g'(\overline{x})$ both exist.  If so, the two-sided limits must equal the one-sided limits above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I believe that there is a typo in the first inequality of the first line. It should be $f(x)\geq g(x)$